# Mapping Surround.vim plugin to add Markdown link in visual mode

Tags: vim, surround

I am using the following plugin to simplify tagging URLs in Markdown:
tpope/vim-surround

This works:

```
nmap <leader>l <Plug>Ysurroundiw]%a(<C-R>*)<Esc>
```

This doesn't (notice the capital 'S'):

```
vmap <leader>l <Plug>YSurround]%a(<C-R>*)<Esc>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `VSurround` instead of `YSurround` since you're using a `vmap`.

Comment: So tricky. I kept typing `verbose vmap S` but still couldn't figure out why it was not working. I should watch out for similarity of V and Y in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Surround is *awesome* but what about a more portable, plugin-agnostic, solution?

```
xnoremap <leader>l <Esc>`>a](<C-r>*)<C-o>`<[<Esc>
```

Comment: Just in case someone was wondering: this will create a markdown link for the selected text with the contents of the clipboard as url 